# Making UIView transparent

Tags: ios, uiview, screen, transparent

I want to add a UIView to my UIViewController but I want it to be transparent until I decide to create an Oval inside the UIView.

Until I create the oval, I can set my view's alpha to 0 but when I want to add the oval, the background color is still black.

here's what it looks like with a bunch of ovals

[image]

In my UIView:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [self pushContext];
    UIBezierPath *oval = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:self.bounds];
    [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
    [oval fill];
    self.opaque = NO;
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    [oval addClip];
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    [self popContext];
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        self.opaque = NO;

    }
    return self;
}



- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.0] setFill];
    UIRectFill(rect);
    [self pushContext];
    UIBezierPath *oval = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:self.bounds];
    [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
    [oval fill];

    [oval addClip];

    [self popContext];
}
```

Answer (score 29):

Please try to use this one

```
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.0];
view.opaque = NO;
```

Comment: To make transparent: `view.isOpaque = false`

Comment: Using `UIColor.clear` will be better choice to standardize the code all over the place.

Answer (score 5):

In your ViewController, you could say that opaque is NO. Let's say, your view is named myCustomView.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.myCustomView.opaque = NO;   
}
```

Or you could just go to the storyboard and uncheck the opaque checkbox like-
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I did semi-transparent background for my UIViewController the same way as it's recommended here but it didn't work until I set **modalPresentationStyle** to **.custom**

my **Swift 4** code:

```
modalPresentationStyle = .custom
view.isOpaque = false
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
```

I open my controller from another one using present(controller, anim, completion) method.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was scratching my head on this for quite a while until I saw your answer. I changed `modalPresentationStyle` to `.custom` and it worked for me too!

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 3.x: (where **layer** is the **view**)

```
layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
layer.isOpaque = false
```

Comment: I got an exception "Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: Swift is an evolving language, which version are you using?